# How to Sort By Association Attribute Value in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but I have a model User which belongs_to a Company model which has a name attribute.

How can I sort all users by their Company name?

```
@users = User.all #sort this collection in order of the associated company's name

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "company_id"
  end

  create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.includes(:company).order('company.name')` . I believe ASC is default, but you can add it if necessary.  You may also have to specify the Company table name in the model, or change the table name to 'companies', as that is the default pluralization convention over configuration will assume I believe.

Comment: This worked, but I had to make it... User.includes(:company).order('companies.name'). I do have the plural form in my table name. I updated my original post to correct this. Is 'companies.name' necessary because this is referring more to the SQL table and column and less to the rails association name?

Comment: yes the table name is what needs to be there.  That is why I had 'company.name' to match what you were showing in the schema.